# Python PyQt Hide QToolbutton Menu arrow

Tags: python, pyqt

I want to hide the `Small Down Arrow` that appears on the `QToolButton` if i set a `QMenu` to it.

I have tried using `StyleSheet` by setting `QToolButton` `menu-arrow` image to none. The following is my Qss code:

```
QToolButton
{
    border:1px solid #B6C4DB;
      border-radius:12px;
      padding:2px;
      margin-left:5px;
}

QToolButton::menu-arrow
{
    image:none;
} 

QToolButton:pressed 
{
         border:1px solid #D6BB0B;
}
```

Is there a way to hide that small arrow on `QToolButton` with a menu?

Comment: just ran into the same problem ad would be interested in the answer

Comment: I just found this (looks like you have to re-implement the paintEvent for now: [link](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-2036)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

posting my comment as a potential answer (at least for now):
Looks like this is a bug but [this page](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-2036) lists a workaround

Comment: thanks it should be `menu indicator` instead of `menu arrow` .. it's working now.

Comment: yes, I didn't notice the comment at the bottom of that page until after I posted the link here - even easier :)

Answer (score 19):

```
QToolButton::menu-indicator { image: none; }
```

Comment: `btn = QToolButton()`
`btn.setStyleSheet('QToolButton::menu-indicator { image: none; }')` 
for those not familiar with the styling syntax

Comment: I just tried this on my button, and it removes the arrow, which I like.  But it still leaves room for the arrow, making the button look lopsided when it has a border around it.  Maybe I can fix that though....

Comment: Ah, fixed it.  It turns out that padding-right is the culprit, in my case at least.  My .qss gives QToolButtons 3px padding normally, so overriding the extra padding like this fixed it for me:  setStyleSheet("* { padding-right: 3px } QToolButton::menu-indicator { image: none }")